# My Python loop in a function is not running again when i call it again from another point

Tags: python, function, debugging

I was solving a question which asked me for an output for a given sequence of input. First input is 'N' which is number of days, second input is a sequence of N integers separated by a Space, Third is Q (number of test-cases) and from forth onward are two Integers(l and r, l < r) separated by a space(Q times).

---

Sample input:

```
5
65 615 16 516 651
5
45 65
63 5635
654 862
0 956
56 89
```

The output I need to generate is how many days are there when the profit is between l and r(both included), for each test case.

Expected output for sample Input:

```
1
4
0
5
1
```

I have written this code in python 3. But it only works for the first test-case, and for all other cases it prints 0.

```
def solve(N,profit,l,r):
    days = 0

    for i in range(N):
        for perdayprofit in profit:
            if l <= perdayprofit <= r :
                days = days + 1
        return days

N = int(input())
profit = map(int,input().split(" "))
Q = int(input())
for i in range(Q):
    l,r = map(int,input().split(" "))
    out = solve(N,profit,l,r)
    print(out)
```

Can someone please explain me what have i done wrong? Or is there any other approach to this question?
I think my solution should work. I am using Jupyterlab and python 3, if you need to know.

Comment: You have a `return` inside the `for` loop. Once you hit `return`, you break out of the function, regardless of the `for` loop.

Comment: That `return days` looks like it's indented too far.  It should probably be outside both `for` loops.

Comment: After looking closer, I don't see a reason for that outer `range(N)` loop at all.

Comment: yes i was just checking for bugs, so i tried iterating this for N times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the indentation of `return days` in your original post is a mistake, the issue is that in python 3 `map()` returns an object that acts as a generator. That means that you can only consume its elements once, e.g.:

```
>>> m = map(lambda x: x + 1, range(10))
>>> list(m)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> list(m)
[]
```

In order to be able to iterate it multiple times, you want to do something like explicitly create a `list`:

```
profit = list(map(int,input().split(" ")))
```

That said, a list comprehension is probably cleaner:

```
profit = [int(i) for i in input().split(" ")]
```

Comment: Thank you, converting it into a list worked! the bottom part of the code was already written out for me, i just had to write the function, so i didn't even bother to check that part of the program, also i didn't know about this property.

Comment: @JatinJangir: This is an easy mistake to make since in python 2 `map()` *did* return a `list` and in many cases the behavior is the same, so this subtle difference is not always obvious.